# Add one more field along with formgroup

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to edit and update user record. I am using formGroup to submit my form. I need to pass and append the "id" field along with formgroup while submiting the update form.

```
  this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({

  firstname: ['', Validators.required],
  lastname: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required]    
  });

i tried:-

 editMethod(userid:any)  {

 this.Form.patchValue({
  id: userid,
 })
 }
```

Patch value is not working I need to append id along with formGroup so that i can update this form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PatchValue don't work because you do not have declarated the control "id" when you build the FormGroup.

the right code:

```
 this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [''],
  firstname: ['', Validators.required],
  lastname: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required]    
  });


 editMethod(userid:any)  {

   this.Form.patchValue({
    id: userid,
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define Id by default and keep it without validation of required.

and patch the value later.

```
 this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [''],  // add this
  firstname: ['', Validators.required],
  lastname: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required]    
  });
```

Moreover you should initialize for with id If it already present like

```
 this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [userid], 
  firstname: ['', Validators.required],
  lastname: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required]    
  });
```

At second time you no need to patch Value as it already present there.

Comment: so we need to use the formbuilder twice ?

Comment: NO use any of one. Better option is to use second one with prefilled value

Comment: so if i use the second one, initially userid i need to set a null, and then in  edit method i need to use patch value to update userid?

Comment: No, Suppose  when you open that edit form and you have userId already then define it like  `id: [userid]`  so no need to do patchValue